# StackOverflow feed on specified tags

Tags: discussion, feed, tags, stack-overflow

Is there a functionality on StackOverflow as subscribing to rss related to specified tags? So a will receive feeds only that has tags i defined?

Comment: i dont see why this is not a viable question for stackoverflow.. if it had been about any other web site or rss feed it would have been acceptable no? poor bugger who asked now has to create a new account.. fail

Comment: Not programming and entirely about how SO works. That's why it's on Meta now. @gor

Answer (score 11):

Create a [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters), then scroll down and click the RSS link.

[Example](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/21857/meta-rss?sort=active), linked from [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/21857/meta-rss).

Comment: Also cool, but I guess filters are 1 tag max eh?  (and see my [other comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105945/stackoverflow-feed-on-specified-tags?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#comment1009574_105949))

Comment: @ashleedawg, one filter can have [multiple tags](https://stackexchange.com/filters/400930/english).

Answer (score 4):

[Here's the feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/off-topic) for posts tagged [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic)

Comment: Sweet... (That particular link is broken but it works with SO tags if you drop the 'meta')  What about multiple tags?  I know [this works as an AND](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/vba%20excel) but what if I want [tag:vba] OR [tag:excel]? Is that possible?

Comment: Offhand, muhdunno